# Puppet：get real-time status of catalog evaluation and post to remote server

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster

According to this article http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/puppet_internals.html

There are four phases when puppet agent got a catalog from master.

resource generation => relationships => evaluation => reporting

```
Reporting

As the transaction progresses, it collects logs and metrics on what it does. At the end
of evaluation, it turns this information into a report, which it sends to the server (if 
requested).
```

And at the end of evaluation puppet agent would generate a report and sent the report to the master.

Is there a way to get real-time status of evaluation phase and post them to a remote logcollector?

Glad for any suggestions.

Comment: is `puppet agent --test --debug` what you want to see?

Comment: I want to get these log and post them to a remote server, puppet don't do this. So maybe i should use something like logstash.

Comment: The Puppet agent writes to syslog by default, so you shouldn't need to jump through any particular hoops to get that syslog data forwarded to a log server of some kind. This is still kind of an odd request, though. I can't see this behavior being much help unless you're doing something like provisioning hundreds of servers at once. At that point, you're probably better off baking a few golden-master images using something like Vagrant and provisioning that way.

Comment: @jgoldschrafe I have 200 servers which need provision, and each server may have different catalog to eval. So i want to develop a system to display every server's real-time status of catalog evaluation. Is it possiable?

Comment: Probably, by forwarding syslog as I mentioned. What are you looking to glean from this information, though? There's probably a better way to do it.

Comment: @jgoldschrafe I want to view what are each server doing immediately, not just after the whole evaluation finished. So it seems i need to use something like Scribe and Flume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all i used Nagios & NSClient++ to collect real-time eventlog of puppet, 
the detail can find here http://blog.medin.name/2012/03/20/real-time-event-log-monitoring-with-nsclient/